# javafx.scene.robot.Robot vs java.awt.Robot

Tags: java, javafx, awt, awtrobot

I just read that JavaFX has its own [`javafx.scene.robot.Robot`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html) class. How does it differ from [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html)?
I also don't really understand why `Robot` class was packed in `java.awt` package instead of e.g. `java.util` as it doesn't seem to be related to GUI components. Could someone explain it please?

Comment: What do their relative API's have to say?

Comment: Comparing the javadoc for both the functionality seems almost the same: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html (JavaFX seems to be lacking the "idle" part though...)

Comment: But do notice the different images that they can create, one that can be used by AWT, BufferedImage, and the other that can be used by JavaFX.

Comment: The difference is also in the implementation. One uses the AWT libraries and the other uses the JavaFX libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the biggest difference is:

The JavaFX Robot must run on the JavaFX thread.

The AWT Robot can run anywhere.